# Resume training in DeepNeuralNetworkLearning Class of accord.net

Tags: c#, deep-learning, accord.net

I'm new to Accord.net.
Is it possible to save the model trained by DeepNeuralNetworkLearning class of Accord.net and then resume training by new samples?

Answer (score 1):

All models in Accord.NET can be saved to disk using the .Save() [extension methods provided by the Serializer class](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_IO_Serializer.htm). Thus it should be possible to save your model when you need and reload it back using Serializer.Load() to resume training later on.